# Is this function holomorphic in $z = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Consider the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{\mathrm{Im}(z^2)}{|z|^2} \qquad (z \neq 0)
$$
with $f(z) = 0$ for $z = 0$. Using $z = x+iy$ we find
$$
f(z) = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2} \ ,
$$
so $u = f$ and $v = 0$ for $f = u + iv$. The derivatives of $u$ are:
$$
u_x = \frac{2y (y^2 - x^2)}{{(x^2+y^2)}^2} \ , \qquad u_y = \frac{2x (x^2 - y^2)}{{(x^2+y^2)}^2} \ .
$$
Then the Cauchy-Riemann equations $u_x = 0$ and $u_y = 0$ imply either $x = y = 0$ or $x = \pm y$, so $f(z)$ is complex differentiable in $z = 0$ and along the lines $x = \pm y$. However, is $f(z)$ holomorphic in $z = 0$? I would say no, because it would have to be complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of $z = 0$, which I don't think it is.

Criticism is welcome, and please point me in the right direction if I'm totally off.

Comment: $f(z)$ is real everywhere (and is not constant) so it is certainly not holomorphic anywhere.

Comment: @GEdgar Great point, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ is not even continuous at $z = 0$, as for $ 0 \neq x \in \mathbb R$, $f(x + ix) = 1$ while $f(0)=0$.

Therefore, $f$ can't be holomorphic at that point.

Comment: You probably meant $f(x + ix) = 1$ instead of $i$?

Comment: @BrunoB Well spotted. Thanks! I' edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure I understand how your example proves that $f$ is not continuous at $z=0$. Is the idea that for $f$ to be continuous, $f(x)$ and $f(x+ix)$ have to approach each other as $x \rightarrow 0$, which isn't the case here?

Comment: @oakley09 That is exactly the point. And to be more specific to approach $0$ as $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up question: Imagine that the CR-equations imply $x = \pm y$ for some continuous function $g$. Is it correct that in this case $g$ would not be holomorphic in $z = 0$, since it would have to be complex differentiable in a neighbourhood of $z = 0$, and not just along the lines $x = \pm y$?

Comment: @oakley09 I would suggest that you precise your point and maybe raise another question as I don't fully understand what you mean. I don't see what to be complex differentiable along a line means.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is this: if we know from the CR-equations that the function is complex differentiable at the points $\{ z = x + iy \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ x = \pm y \}$, is it holomorphic anywhere?

Comment: @oakley09 There is no reason for that as far as I know.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That's what I figured as well. Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0):

> Along $y=mx$; the limiting value of function is:
> $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2xmx}{x^2+(mx)^2}=\frac{2m}{1+m^2}$\which depends on $m$; 
> so even the value of $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(z)$ fails to exist.